# Filling the area delimited by several curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I'm trying to draw the feasible set of a maximization problem. I've been able to draw the boundary of it, but I'm struggling to shade it. I understand that my `fill between` statement fills the area delimited by the y-axis (from 0 to 1) and f_2, but it's not clear to me at all what part of the statement is actually limiting the shading to occur between 0 and 1. I'd like to modify the statement so it limited the shading to (Sqrt[14]/5,1) and then add another that shaded the area between the y-axis and f_5 (0,Sqrt[14]/5).

Alternatively, I'd be happy if I could fill in white the area between f_2 and f_5 from the intersection down. To this last end, I've tried adding

```
\addplot[fill=none] fill between [of=constraint_2 and constraint_5, split, every segment no 1/.style={fill,blue},on layer={axis background}];
```

right after the previous `fill between` instruction, and this indeed solves my problem. However, I feel it's an awkward solution.

Of course, I'm open to other, better solutions. Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[
          xlabel={$q_1$},
          ylabel={$q_2$},
          every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=west},
          every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south},
          ticks=none, 
          axis x line=bottom,
          axis y line=left,
          xmin=0, xmax=2.2,
          ymin=0, ymax=2,
          y axis line style={name path=yaxis},
          ]
       \addplot[
          name path=constraint_2,
          domain=0:sqrt(2),
          samples=200,
          y filter/.expression={x==sqrt(2)?0:y},
          thick,
          ] {sqrt(2-x^2)};
       \addplot[
          name path=constraint_5,
          domain=0:sqrt(122/75),
          samples=200,
          y filter/.expression={x==sqrt(122/75)?0:y},
          thick,
          ] {sqrt((122/25-3*x^2)/1)};
       \addplot[gray,opacity = 0.1] fill between [of=yaxis and constraint_2, reverse=false, soft clip={(-1,-1) rectangle (1,1)}, on layer={axis background}];
       \addplot[fill=none] fill between [of=constraint_2 and constraint_5, split, every segment no 1/.style={fill,blue},on layer={axis background}];
       \addplot[
          domain = 0:7,
          samples =2,
          thick
          ] {1};
       \node at (axis cs: 1,1.6) {$f_5$};
       \node at (axis cs: 0.45,1.47) {$f_2$};
       \node at (axis cs: 1.9,1.07) {$f_1$};
       \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and its output

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you want to achieve, but it may be easier to use a regular `\fill` command (in combination with a helper `\path`) and the `intersection segments` option if you want to fill the area defined by the two axes, f1, f2 and f5.

The following code first creates a named path that combines the relevant sections of f2 and f5 and then combines this path with f1 (which I named `constraint_3`). Since your plots start and end at y = 0 and x = 0 respectively, it is then easy to use this combined path to create a polygon with another point at the origin and fill it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[
          xlabel={$q_1$},
          ylabel={$q_2$},
          every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=west},
          every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south},
          ticks=none, 
          axis x line=bottom,
          axis y line=left,
          xmin=0, xmax=2.2,
          ymin=0, ymax=2,
          y axis line style={name path=yaxis},
          ]
       \addplot[
          name path=constraint_2,
          domain=0:sqrt(2),
          samples=200,
          y filter/.expression={x==sqrt(2)?0:y},
          thick,
          ] {sqrt(2-x^2)};
       \addplot[
          name path=constraint_5,
          domain=0:sqrt(122/75),
          samples=200,
          y filter/.expression={x==sqrt(122/75)?0:y},
          thick,
          ] {sqrt((122/25-3*x^2)/1)};
       \addplot[
          name path=constraint_3,
          domain = 0:7,
          samples = 2,
          thick
          ] {1};
       \path[name path=helper_path, intersection segments={of=constraint_2 and constraint_5, sequence={L1 -- R2}]}];
       \fill[gray, opacity=0.1, intersection segments={of=constraint_3 and helper_path, sequence={L1 -- R2}]}] -- (0,0) -- cycle;
       \node at (axis cs: 1,1.6) {$f_5$};
       \node at (axis cs: 0.45,1.47) {$f_2$};
       \node at (axis cs: 1.9,1.07) {$f_1$};
       \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea about what you describe, so I just fill some random areas:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center, axis equal,
xlabel={$q_1$}, ylabel={$q_2$},
every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=west},
every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south},
ticks=none, 
xmin=0, xmax=2.2,
ymin=0, ymax=2,
y axis line style={name path=yaxis},
]
\addplot[
name path=constraint_2,
domain=0:sqrt(2),
samples=200,
y filter/.expression={x==sqrt(2)?0:y},
thick,
] {sqrt(2-x^2)} node[above, pos=0.2]{$f_2$};
\addplot[
name path=constraint_5,
domain=0:sqrt(122/75),
samples=200,
y filter/.expression={x==sqrt(122/75)?0:y},
thick,
] {sqrt(122/25-3*x^2)} node[above right, pos=0.4]{$f_5$};
\addplot[
name path=constraint_1,
domain=0:2.2, samples=2, 
thick] {1} node[above, pos=0.8]{$f_1$};
\fill ({sqrt(14)/5},1) circle[radius=1.5pt] node[pin={[pin distance=1.2cm]40:{$\scriptscriptstyle \left(\frac{\sqrt{14}}{5} , 1\right)$}}]{};
\addplot[gray, opacity=0.5] fill between [of=yaxis and constraint_2, reverse=false];
\addplot[red, opacity=0.5] fill between [of=constraint_1 and constraint_2,
soft clip={(0,0) rectangle ({sqrt(14)/5},2)},
];
\addplot[fill=none] fill between [of=constraint_2 and constraint_5, split,
every segment no 1/.style={fill, green}
];
\addplot[blue, opacity=0.5] fill between [of=yaxis and constraint_2,
soft clip={(0,{sqrt(14)/5}) rectangle (2,1)},
];
\addplot[blue, opacity=0.5] fill between [of=yaxis and constraint_5,
soft clip={(0,0) rectangle (2,{sqrt(14)/5})},
];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with several filled areas]